# Python: function with list of arguments of variable length

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot  (on the same figure) some data from an Excel sheet, and I want as an input a variable length list of strings, corresponding to different materials. I get the following error:
 TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
I really don't understand why. Here is the code:

```
import xlrd
import matplotlib.pyplot  as plt
from numpy import *
def transmittance(*glass):
    wb=xlrd.open_workbook('schott_optical_glass_catalogue_excel_december_2012.xls')
    sheet1=wb.sheet_by_index(0)
    transm_index=[]  #lista vuota
    plt.figure(1)
    plt.xlabel('wavelength $\lambda$[nm]')
    plt.ylabel('transmittance')
    for item in glass:
        for i in range(sheet1.nrows):
            if sheet1.cell_value(i,0)==glass:
                reversed_transmission=sheet1.row_values(i,37,67)
                transm_index=reversed_transmission[::-1]
                new_transm_index=[float(ni)  for ni in transm_index ]
    wavel_range=sheet1.row_values(3,37,67)
    temp_wavel= [k.split('/')[1] for k in wavel_range]
    wRange=map(int,temp_wavel[::-1])
    plt.plot(wRange,new_transm_index, 'r-')
    plt.grid(True, which="both")
    plt.show()
    return new_transm_index, wRange

if __name__=='__main__':
    new_transm_index=transmittance('N-BASF64','N-BK7')
    print 'get tuple length and glass name: ' ,new_transm_index
```

Comment: You might get more responses if you add a tag for the language.

Comment: I edited the whitespace to make it at least syntactically correct, but I'm not sure it's exactly what you want, @Ivranovi--could you review it?

Comment: Also, could you show us how you call `transmittance` and what the full text of the error is?

Comment: I would like to retrieve a 'dynamic' array of lists for the returned args, namely not only for the last item, but for all

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce the TypeError you describe in your question (which I would probably get if I called `transmittance()` without any parameters). However, I get two different errors instead, when calling your function with an XLS file of the same name I found via Google.

- You iterate the items in `glass`, but then compare to the whole list instead of to the current `item`
- When you create the `new_transm_index` list, you can't just cast to `float`, as there are some empty strings in the table; in this case I would assume the value to be zero.

Finally, if you want the `new_transm_index` to hold a list for each item from `glass` (as described in your comment), you should use a dictionary, mapping the items (keys) to the respective lists (values).

```
...
new_transm_index = {} # create dictionary
for item in glass:
    for i in range(sheet1.nrows):
        if sheet1.cell_value(i, 0) == item: # compare to item, not to list
            ...
            # do not cast ' ' to float, but use 0 if not of type float
            new_transm_index[item] = [ni if type(ni) == float else 0 for ni in transm_index]
...
for item in glass: # add plots for all items to common diagram
    plt.plot(wRange,new_transm_index[item])
plt.grid(True, which="both")
plt.show()
...
```

Comment: cool!Great, thanks a lot! Is there a way to plot the curves automatically with different colors?

Comment: @Ivranovi When I tested it, it _did_ draw the curves automatically with different colors; one in blue, the other in green. Doesn't it for your?